# Applying do while loops

Tags: java, do-while

My code is currently unable to start at the beginning of the program which is 'Please type in...'.  I want the code to be able to return to the beginning statement everytime choice 1 or 2 is executed. The while statement does not satisfy this as I cant use the while statement before 'choice' is declared. I understand that I'm suppose to be using a *do while* loop but everytime I try to implement it - it gives me an error with braces.

The following is a snippet of my code:

```
    System.out.println("Please type in 1 for a customer to view their portfolio, 2 to trade stocks or 3 to exit the application");
    int choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    {
while (!"3".equals(choice));
    { 
        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println(mycustomers[menuchoice].toString());
            return;
                         }
        if (choice == 2) {
            String StockSelect = "Please select a stock";
            for (int i = 0; i < mystocks.length; i++) {
                // [i] is the element we are accessing
                StockSelect += " " + i + " " + (mystocks[i].getSymbol());
            }

            System.out.println(StockSelect);

            int stockchoice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Select 1 to buy or 2 to sell?");
            int choice2 = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

            if (choice2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("How many stocks would you like to buy ");
                int volumebought = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                for (int i = 0; i < numofstocks; i++) {
                    mycustomers[menuchoice].setBalance(
                            mycustomers[menuchoice].getBalance() - (volumebought * mystocks[i].getprice()));
                    mycustomers[menuchoice].setPortfolio();
                }
                System.out.println(mycustomers[menuchoice].toString());
                return;
            }
            if (choice2 == 2) {
                System.out.println("How much stocks would you like to sell ");
                int volumesold = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                for (int i = 0; i < numofstocks; i++) {
                    mycustomers[menuchoice].setBalance(
                            mycustomers[menuchoice].getBalance() + (volumesold * mystocks[i].getprice()));
                            mycustomers[menuchoice].setPortfolio();
                }
                System.out.println(mycustomers[menuchoice].toString());
                return;
            }

        }
        if (choice == 3) // how to exit application
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the application");
            System.out.println("The current state of all customers are:");
            for (int i = 0; i < mycustomers.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(mycustomers[i].toString());
            }
            System.out.println("The current state of all stocks are:");
            for (int i = 0; i < mystocks.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(mystocks[i].toString());
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

}}}
```

How would I implement the do-while loop so that it goes back to the initial statement every time after executing the code - if only if the input is not 3?

Comment: That isn't a do while loop

Comment: Try while(choice != 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for input inside the while loop, like this:

```
choice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Comment: i've asked for input inside the while loop but it still underlines "choice" in red, indicating that i still need to initialize the variable before I use the statment in a while loop

Comment: @KonfuChicken Don't remove the line at the top. Additionally, your while loop has a semicolon after it so it won't do anything, and your if statement will never be reached. Also, since you turned choice into an int, your condition should be `choice != 3`